# Watts and Newtons revisited

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, power

> At the junkyard, an electromagnet holds a 1 ton car freely in the air (no acceleration exc. gravity). Assuming 100% power efficiency, how many Watt electrical power are needed?

I know that the magnet produces 10,000 N, but in order to get the $W$, I'd need some velocity (W = Nm/s), and I don't see any m/s?

This question is actually a reformulation of "how much power do we need to accelerate a 1 ton electric car with 1g?" and I'm aware that the answer to this usually is "infinite" (because of division by zero speed). But the above electromagnet sure draws a finite amout of power, and since there's no movement, the formula which divides by $v$ cannot apply.

Comment: Just holding a car still in the air doesn't do any work on it, so from a conservation of energy standpoint no energy at all needs to be used. An electromagnet will use power holding the car because of $I^2R$ electric power dissipation but the amount of power required will all depend on the details of the electromagnet, weight of the car, the metals making up the car, etc.. Also, don't understand your "1 ton electric car with 1g" comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Work being done as the applied force on the car does not result in it's motion. However there will be power draw in real life electromagnets due to electrical resistance in the coil windings. In your case you defined 100% power efficiency which would be interpreted as zero resistance wires--you are effectively describing a permanent magnet here (i.e. a magnet that consumes no added electrical energy to work) which I would suggest is an intuitive way to understand that no Work is being done. Long story short, a 100% power efficiency electromagnet does not need any electrical power to lift that car, or any ferromagnetic object for that matter!